# Target class [ProductController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-9

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;

Route::post('/products/{qty}/add', 'ProductController@addProduct')->name('addProduct');
```

**products-list.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('addProduct', 1) }}" method="post" class="ui form">
  <input type="text" name="qty" value="1" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

**app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function addProduct(Request $request, $qty)
    {
        dd($qty);
    }
}
```

But the controller class exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespacing won't help in this scenario, because it's just a string:

```
Route::post('/products/{qty}/add', 'ProductController@addProduct')
```

This will work:

```
Route::post('/products/{qty}/add', [ProductController::class, 'addProduct'])
```

or you can do:

```
Route::post('/products/{qty}/add', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@addProduct')
```

Comment: I now have to use this with `<form action="/products/1/add" method="post" class="ui form">` to prevent a `route doesn't exist` error for an immediate fix.

Comment: That's because you never named your route. You need `->name('addProduct')` on the route definition to use `route('addProduct', 1)` in the view. Route names and *function* names are not the same thing.